# android whitespace at bottom of recyclerview appears when toolbar added to layout

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my application im using CoordinatorLayout,AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout because i want my app to have top menu bar pinned and header which hides on scroll. I have recyclerview where my items are listed, and items are made in CardView.

Problem is that when i add toolbar as CollapsingToolbarLayouts child at bottom of screen,under recyclerview, on my phone whitespace appears. Also whitespaces dimensions are same like toolbars. When i remove toolbar whitespace also disappears.

here is my main xml code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/GrayColour"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                <include
                    android:id="@+id/Header"
                    layout="@layout/header_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/TopBar"
                    layout="@layout/top_navigation_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is my xml code for items with who recyclerview is filled:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_background_rounded_corners"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/white_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCategory"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/category"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/android_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCategoryName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```